# Continuous Integration, Creating Bots with XCode 4.6.3 or Only XCode 5.0

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-server

Now with the release iOS 7, XCode 5.0 and OS X Server there's a feature called "Continuous Integration" where we can build, test and analyse proyects, all this tasks can be performed creating "bots", but my question is, Is this feature only for XCode 5.0?, I mean, there's something similar in XCode 4.6.3?

Comment: What is the feature in 4.6.3? I was under the impression bots were >=5 only

Answer (score 1):

Bots are new feature introduced with Xcode 5.0. You cannot create bots from earlier versions of Xcode.

Comment: OK Thanks..But, with "Continuous Integration" feature, Could I create "bots" to build an a AppStore product?, i mean, build a final iphone/ipad project (.app) ready to be send to AppStore, set the AppStore provisioning profile...etc or this feature is only for developer environments, to test archives, distribution .IPAs and so on...?

Comment: Bots cannot package apps for release to the App Store. Have a read of the [Xcode Continuous Integration Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/000-About_Continuous_Integration/about_continuous_integration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH1-SW1).

Comment: What is the reason to lose my reputation, is just a question?...i read the doc...reason for this question is, "i have a lot of targets, to build different app to AppStore, in unique project, and i would like to automate the process to set AppStore provisioning, images, build, etc. because is so tedious"...thanks @neilco